# NameValueCollection to URL Query?

Tags: asp.net, url, url-encoding, namevaluecollection

I know i can do this

```
var nv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(req.RawUrl);
```

But is there a way to convert this back to a url?

```
var newUrl = HttpUtility.Something("/page", nv);
```

Answer (score 135):

Simply calling `ToString()` on the `NameValueCollection` will return the name value pairs in a `name1=value1&name2=value2` querystring ready format. Note that `NameValueCollection` types don't actually support this and it's misleading to suggest this, but the behavior works here due to the internal type that's actually returned, as explained below.

Thanks to @mjwills for pointing out that the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` method actually returns an internal `HttpValueCollection` object rather than a regular `NameValueCollection` ([despite the documentation specifying `NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx)). The `HttpValueCollection` automatically encodes the querystring when using `ToString()`, so there's no need to write a routine that loops through the collection and uses the `UrlEncode` method. The desired result is already returned.

With the result in hand, you can then append it to the URL and redirect:

```
var nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "?" + nameValues.ToString();
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Currently the only way to use a `HttpValueCollection` is by using the `ParseQueryString` method shown above (other than reflection, of course). It looks like this won't change since the [Connect issue requesting this class be made public](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/356144/make-the-httpvaluecollection-class-public-and-move-it-to-system-dll) has been closed with a status of "won't fix."

As an aside, you can call the `Add`, `Set`, and `Remove` methods on `nameValues` to modify any of the querystring items before appending it. If you're interested in that [see my response to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813934/change-single-url-query-string-value/3814281#3814281).

Comment: I'm unsure nameValues.ToString() will escape properly.

Comment: Actually you can just use qs.ToString().

This is because qs is not a NameValueCollection (despite the method signature of HttpUtility.ParseQueryString). It is actually a private type called System.Web.HttpValueCollection (you can check this using qs.GetType()).

NameValueCollection.ToString() doesn't url encode, but HttpValueCollection.ToString() does. So your use of StringBuilder is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @mjwills thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't aware of `HttpValueCollection` being returned and that it encodes everything. It keeps the code simple. Updated my response :)

Comment: My earlier comment is likely incorrect. HttpValueCollection doesn't call HttpUtility.UrlEncode - instead it seems to call HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode (http://tinyurl.com/HttpValue). This is a problem since the two differ in how they handle some characters (e.g. é). The new documentation for UrlEncodeUnicode seems to suggest it shouldn't be used - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencodeunicode(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: `NameValueCollection.ToString()` returns `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` string (literally), not the "name value pairs in a querystring ready format".

Comment: @IgorBrejc thanks, I've updated my post to say it's misleading to state that `NameValueCollection` returns the expected format. The MSDN documentation is also misleading since it says `ParseQueryString` returns a `NameValueCollection` although it's actually `HttpValueCollection` and calling `ToString()` on that should return the expected format as the rest of the answer mentions.

Comment: I also found that NameValueCollection.ToString() does not format to a query string.

Comment: Following up on my earlier comment, this solution here will work reliably but **only** if you set `aspnet:DontUsePercentUUrlEncoding` to true. See http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Beware-NameValueCollectionToString-and-DontUsePercentUUrlEncoding.aspx .

Comment: i am late here because you alredy update the post, but i will point it out this is extremely missleading because the question is related to NameValueCollection and you answer refer to HttpValueCollection. I see you have updated the info, but the answer seems offtopic imho (if i start from a NameValueCollection, how can i get a well formatted query string? this is the question asked, as title said)

Answer (score 79):

```
string q = String.Join("&",
             nvc.AllKeys.Select(a => a + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nvc[a])));
```

Comment: This answer is the only one that will correctly handle encoding in the url parameters. Kudos!

Comment: also the only one that answers the literal question regarding `NameValueCollections`, rather than the provided scenario which involves `HttpValueCollection` instead

Comment: I don't think this will work correctly if there are multiple values for the same key.

Comment: @MartinBrown is right, it doesn't. Here's what works with multivalued namevaluecollections: uriBuilder.Query += String.Join("&", parameters.AllKeys.SelectMany(key => (parameters.GetValues(key) ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>()).Select(val => String.Concat(key, "=", WebUtility.UrlEncode(val)))));

Comment: You should encode the key too: 
`string q = String.Join("&", nvc.AllKeys.Select(a => HttpUtility.UrlEncode(a) + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nvc[a])));`

Comment: I don't think this works when the collection contains multiple values for the same name

Answer (score 26):

Make an extension method that uses a couple of loops. I prefer this solution because it's readable (no linq), doesn't require System.Web.HttpUtility, and it supports duplicate keys.

```
public static string ToQueryString(this NameValueCollection nvc)
{
    if (nvc == null) return string.Empty;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key)) continue;

        string[] values = nvc.GetValues(key);
        if (values == null) continue;

        foreach (string value in values)
        {
            sb.Append(sb.Length == 0 ? "?" : "&");
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(key), Uri.EscapeDataString(value));
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

### Example

```
var queryParams = new NameValueCollection()
{
    { "order_id", "0000" },
    { "item_id", "1111" },
    { "item_id", "2222" },
    { null, "skip entry with null key" },
    { "needs escaping", "special chars ? = &" },
    { "skip entry with null value", null }
};

Console.WriteLine(queryParams.ToQueryString());
```

### Output

```
?order_id=0000&item_id=1111&item_id=2222&needs%20escaping=special%20chars%20%3F%20%3D%20%26
```

Answer (score 21):

This should work without too much code:

```
NameValueCollection nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
nameValues.Add(Request.QueryString);
// modify nameValues if desired
var newUrl = "/page?" + nameValues;
```

The idea is to use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to generate an empty collection of type `HttpValueCollection`.  This class is a subclass of `NameValueCollection` that is marked as `internal` so that your code cannot easily create an instance of it.

The nice thing about `HttpValueCollection` is that the `ToString` method takes care of the encoding for you.  By leveraging the `NameValueCollection.Add(NameValueCollection)` method, you can add the existing query string parameters to your newly created object without having to first convert the `Request.QueryString` collection into a url-encoded string, then parsing it back into a collection.

This technique can be exposed as an extension method as well:

```
public static string ToQueryString(this NameValueCollection nameValueCollection)
{
    NameValueCollection httpValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
    httpValueCollection.Add(nameValueCollection);
    return httpValueCollection.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually, you should encode the key too, not just value.

```
string q = String.Join("&",
nvc.AllKeys.Select(a => $"{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(a)}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nvc[a])}"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Because a `NameValueCollection` can have multiple values for the same key, if you are concerned with the format of the querystring (since it will be returned as comma-separated values rather than "array notation") you may consider the following.

### Example

```
var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("key1", "val1");
nvc.Add("key2", "val2");
nvc.Add("empty", null);
nvc.Add("key2", "val2b");
```

Turn into: `key1=val1&key2[]=val2&empty&key2[]=val2b` rather than `key1=val1&key2=val2,val2b&empty`.

### Code

```
string qs = string.Join("&", 
    // "loop" the keys
    nvc.AllKeys.SelectMany(k => {
        // "loop" the values
        var values = nvc.GetValues(k);
        if(values == null) return new[]{ k };
        return nvc.GetValues(k).Select( (v,i) => 
            // 'gracefully' handle formatting
            // when there's 1 or more values
            string.Format(
                values.Length > 1
                    // pick your array format: k[i]=v or k[]=v, etc
                    ? "{0}[]={1}"
                    : "{0}={1}"
                , k, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(v), i)
        );
    })
);
```

or if you don't like Linq so much...

```
string qs = nvc.ToQueryString(); // using...

public static class UrlExtensions {
    public static string ToQueryString(this NameValueCollection nvc) {
        return string.Join("&", nvc.GetUrlList());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetUrlList(this NameValueCollection nvc) {
        foreach(var k in nvc.AllKeys) {
            var values = nvc.GetValues(k);
            if(values == null)  { yield return k; continue; }
            for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
                yield return
                // 'gracefully' handle formatting
                // when there's 1 or more values
                string.Format(
                    values.Length > 1
                        // pick your array format: k[i]=v or k[]=v, etc
                        ? "{0}[]={1}"
                        : "{0}={1}"
                    , k, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(values[i]), i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As has been pointed out in comments already, with the exception of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19617268/1037948) most of the other answers address the scenario (`Request.QueryString` is an `HttpValueCollection`, "not" a `NameValueCollection`) rather than the literal question.

*Update:* addressed null value issue from comment.

Comment: Good idea, but your linq code doesn't check for null. How can you guarantee that nvc.GetValues(k) doesn't return null?

Comment: @tianxu0836 good call; I assumed a key without a value would return an empty string, but guess not.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is to use `.ToString()` on the `NameValueCollection` and combine it with the original url.

However, I'd like to point out a few things:

You cant use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` on `Request.RawUrl`. The `ParseQueryString()` method is looking for a value like this: `?var=value&var2=value2`.

If you want to get a `NameValueCollection` of the `QueryString` parameters just use `Request.QueryString()`.

```
var nv = Request.QueryString;
```

To rebuild the URL just use nv.ToString().

```
string url = String.Format("{0}?{1}", Request.Path, nv.ToString());
```

If you are trying to parse a url string instead of using the `Request` object use `Uri` and the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` method.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("<THE URL>");
var nv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
string url = String.Format("{0}?{1}", uri.AbsolutePath, nv.ToString());
```

Comment: like a comment on [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3866105/1037948) pointed out (and basically repeating here), `Request.QueryString` isn't actually a `NameValueCollection`, it's a special derivative `HttpValueCollection` which is why `.ToString` works; on a regular nvc you'll have to use something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19617268/1037948) instead

Answer (score 2):

I always use UriBuilder to convert an url with a querystring back to a valid and properly encoded url.

```
var url = "http://my-link.com?foo=bar";

var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
query.Add("yep", "foo&bar");

uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
var result = uriBuilder.ToString();

// http://my-link.com:80/?foo=bar&yep=foo%26bar
```

Answer (score 2):

In AspNet Core 2.0 you can use [QueryHelpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers?view=aspnetcore-2.0) AddQueryString method.

Answer (score 0):

As @Atchitutchuk suggested, you can use QueryHelpers.AddQueryString in ASP.NET Core:

```
    public string FormatParameters(NameValueCollection parameters)
    {
        var queryString = "";
        foreach (var key in parameters.AllKeys)
        {
            foreach (var value in parameters.GetValues(key))
            {
                queryString = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(queryString, key, value);
            }
        };

        return queryString.TrimStart('?');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
public ActionResult SetLanguage(string language = "fr_FR")
        {            
            Request.UrlReferrer.TryReadQueryAs(out RouteValueDictionary parameters);            
            parameters["language"] = language;            
            return RedirectToAction("Index", parameters);            
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use.

```
var ur = new Uri("/page",UriKind.Relative);
```

if this nv is of type string you can append to the uri first parameter.
Like

```
var ur2 = new Uri("/page?"+nv.ToString(),UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: +nv ... that wont escape properly.