# Is it possible to get list of query string parameters and change 1 of the parameter and pass as parameter

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I stuck with one simple thing:

I have URL
http://mydomain.com/PagedPage?Page=1&PageSize=30&SortOrder=Name

I want to pass list of parameters as parameter to my custom Html.Pager helper but inside pager I should be able to edit the parameter "Page"

Is it possible to do without hardcoding data?

---

UPDATED:
in cshtml page I have this helper (it is custom helper)
@Html.Pager(Model.Page, Model.TotalPages, Model.TotalRecords, )

Inside pager I want to generate links:
Page=1, Page=2, Page=3 etc but also ALL parameters which were passed inside html helper must be included.

---

Thank you!

Comment: I've no clue of what you're trying to archive, perhaps you could elaborate a bit more.

Comment: I want to pass this: Page=1&PageSize=30&SortOrder=Name as collection or key value, and have ability to change the "page" parameter inside this list and have ability to create new URL like: Page=10&PageSize...

Comment: @Sergey you mean in between the request and response, like a redirect?

Comment: Can´t you just use Request.QueryString, and create a new collection with the same fields only changing the ones you need?

Comment: I am creating good example for this. give me a few moments please

Comment: It is very interesting task btw and will be useful for a lot of people

Comment: I've updated the question, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `Request.QueryString` is the querystring, change one of the entries in the querystring, add rest of them and create a new querystring and pass that to the next page.

Comment: Thank you! Also this question and answer helped me a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865975/namevaluecollection-to-url-query

Comment: Please vote my question I am sure I am not single person who looked on it