# Build query string for System.Net.HttpClient get

Tags: c#, .net, http

If I wish to submit a http get request using System.Net.HttpClient there seems to be no api to add parameters, is this correct?

Is there any simple api available to build the query string that doesn't involve building a name value collection and url encoding those and then finally concatenating them?
I was hoping to use something like RestSharp's api (i.e AddParameter(..))

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud you may want to reconsider using the accepted answer with  characters which need encoding, see my explanation below

Answer (score 433, accepted):

> If I wish to submit a http get request using System.Net.HttpClient
>   there seems to be no api to add parameters, is this correct?

Yes.

> Is there any simple api available to build the query string that
>   doesn't involve building a name value collection and url encoding
>   those and then finally concatenating them?

Sure:

```
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
query["foo"] = "bar<>&-baz";
query["bar"] = "bazinga";
string queryString = query.ToString();
```

will give you the expected result:

```
foo=bar%3c%3e%26-baz&bar=bazinga
```

You might also find the `UriBuilder` class useful:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder("http://example.com");
builder.Port = -1;
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
query["foo"] = "bar<>&-baz";
query["bar"] = "bazinga";
builder.Query = query.ToString();
string url = builder.ToString();
```

will give you the expected result:

```
http://example.com/?foo=bar%3c%3e%26-baz&bar=bazinga
```

that you could more than safely feed to your `HttpClient.GetAsync` method.

Comment: I've used the `ParseQueryString` method as well, works good man.

Comment: That's the absolute best in terms of url handling in .NET. No need to ever be manually url encoding and doing string concatenations or string builders or whatever. The UriBuilder class will even handle urls with fragments (`#`) for you using the Fragment property. I have seen so many people doing the mistake of manually handling urls instead of using the built-in tools.

Comment: I agree that it's definitely the easiest to use, but it's dealing with undocumented functionality.  If you were to do `new NameValueCollection` (which `ParseQueryString` returns), you cannot do `.ToString()` on it and expect the same results.

Comment: What do you mean by undocumented functionality? The ParseQueryString method returns a derived class of NameValueCollection which takes care of all the url encoding for you. The [`ParseQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) seems pretty well documented.

Comment: `NameValueCollection.ToString()` normally does not make query strings, and there's no documentation stating that doing a `ToString` on the result of `ParseQueryString` will result in a new query string, thus could break at any time as there's no guarantee in that functionality.

Comment: HttpUtility is in System.Web which is not available on portable runtime. It seems strange that this functionality isn't more generally available in the class libraries.

Comment: This solution is despicable. .Net should have proper querystring builder.

Comment: @Kugel How is .NET's proper querystring builder or lack thereof related to this answer's despicability or lack thereof?

Comment: The fact that the best solution is hidden in the internal class to which you can only get by calling an utility method passing in empty string can't be exactly called an elegant solution.

Comment: This solution works well but I don't like having to include System.Web to use it.

Comment: I assume this would not work for producing a query string with multiple values for a key (eg. `foo=1&foo=2&foo=3`)? Any convenient alternatives?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov just wanted to give you guys the heads up - DO NOT use builder.Uri (which I expected to be proper way to get Uri), as it will give double encoded url, see my answer

Comment: @label17 It does work if you use the syntax: `query.Add("foo", "1");`, since `ParseQueryString` parses into a NameValueCollection which allowes duplicates.

Comment: For those thinking about the `System.Web` namespace, the `HttpUtility` is available in .Net Standard and .Net Core unlike most other classes in the namespace which means they're not getting deprecated any time soon and will continue being a standard way of doing this.

Comment: Can you explain in the answer why you set port to -1?

Answer (score 107):

For those who do not want to include `System.Web` in projects that don't already use it, you can use [`FormUrlEncodedContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent) from `System.Net.Http` and do something like the following:

### keyvaluepair version

```
string query;
using(var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ham", "Glazed?"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("x-men", "Wolverine + Logan"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Time", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
})) {
    query = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

### dictionary version

```
string query;
using(var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "ham", "Glaced?"},
    { "x-men", "Wolverine + Logan"},
    { "Time", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() },
})) {
    query = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a using statement?

Comment: Likely to free up resources, but this is over-the-top. Don't do this.

Comment: This can be more concise by using Dictionary<string, string> instead of the KVP array. Then using initializer syntax of: { "ham", "Glazed?" }

Comment: @SeanB That's a nice idea, especially when using something to add a dynamic / unknown list of parameters. For this example since it's a "fixed" list, I didn't feel like the overhead of a dictionary was worth it.

Comment: @Kody Why do you say to not to use `dispose`? I always dispose unless I have a good reason not to, like reusing `HttpClient`.

Comment: @DanFriedman I think he meant that the _solution_ is over the top, as it requires allocating several new objects and running an asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 101):

In a ASP.NET Core project you can use the `QueryHelpers` class, available in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` namespace for ASP.NET Core, or the .NET Standard 2.0 [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/) for other consumers:

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
var query = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["foo"] = "bar",
    ["foo2"] = "bar2",
    // ...
};

var response = await client.GetAsync(QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("/api/", query));
```

Comment: Its annoying that although with this process you still cannot send multiple value for the same key. If you want to send "bar" and "bar2" as part of just foo, it is not possible.

Comment: This is a great answer for modern apps, works in my scenario, simple and clean. However, I don't need any escape mechanisms - not tested.

Comment: This NuGet package targets .NET standard 2.0 which means you can use it on the full .NET framework 4.6.1+

Comment: Also available in `Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.WebUtilities.AddQueryString()` according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40308437/470014

Comment: I found this solution useful. I just extended this solution like below and used it. 

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(this HttpClient httpClient, string url, Dictionary<string, string?> queries)
        {
            string uri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, queries);
            return await httpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

Comment: @m0g Now you can with [AddQueryString(String, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,StringValues>>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers.addquerystring?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-webutilities-queryhelpers-addquerystring(system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-collections-generic-keyvaluepair((system-string-microsoft-extensions-primitives-stringvalues))))))

Answer (score 52):

**TL;DR: do not use accepted version as It's completely broken in relation to handling unicode characters, and never use internal API**

**I've actually found weird double encoding issue with the accepted solution:**

So, If you're dealing with characters which need to be encoded, accepted solution leads to double encoding:

- query parameters are auto encoded by using `NameValueCollection` indexer (**and this uses `UrlEncodeUnicode`, not regular expected `UrlEncode`(!)**)
- Then, when you call `uriBuilder.Uri` it creates new `Uri` using constructor **which does encoding one more time** (normal url encoding)
- **That cannot be avoided by doing `uriBuilder.ToString()`** (even though this returns correct `Uri` which IMO is at least inconsistency, maybe a bug, but that's another question) and then using `HttpClient` method accepting string - **client still creates `Uri` out of your passed string like this: `new Uri(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)`**

Small, but full repro:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder
{
    Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
    Port = -1,
    Host = "127.0.0.1",
    Path = "app"
};

NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);

query["cyrillic"] = "кирилиця";

builder.Query = query.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(builder.Query); //query with cyrillic stuff UrlEncodedUnicode, and that's not what you want

var uri = builder.Uri; // creates new Uri using constructor which does encode and messes cyrillic parameter even more
Console.WriteLine(uri);

// this is still wrong:
var stringUri = builder.ToString(); // returns more 'correct' (still `UrlEncodedUnicode`, but at least once, not twice)
new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(stringUri); // this creates Uri object out of 'stringUri' so we still end up sending double encoded cyrillic text to server. Ouch!
```

Output:

```
?cyrillic=%u043a%u0438%u0440%u0438%u043b%u0438%u0446%u044f

https://127.0.0.1/app?cyrillic=%25u043a%25u0438%25u0440%25u0438%25u043b%25u0438%25u0446%25u044f
```

As you may see, no matter if you do `uribuilder.ToString()` + `httpClient.GetStringAsync(string)` or `uriBuilder.Uri` + `httpClient.GetStringAsync(Uri)` you end up sending double encoded parameter

Fixed example could be:

```
var uri = new Uri(builder.ToString(), dontEscape: true);
new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(uri);
```

But this uses **obsolete** `Uri` constructor

P.S on my latest .NET on Windows Server, `Uri` constructor with bool doc comment says "obsolete, dontEscape is always false", but actually works as expected (skips escaping)

So It looks like another bug...

**And even this is plain wrong - it send UrlEncodedUnicode to server, not just UrlEncoded what server expects**

Update: one more thing is, NameValueCollection actually does UrlEncodeUnicode, which is not supposed to be used anymore and is incompatible with regular url.encode/decode (see [NameValueCollection to URL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865975/namevaluecollection-to-url-query#comment14763595_3866105)).

So the bottom line is: **never use this hack with `NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);`** as it will mess your unicode query parameters. Just build query manually and assign it to `UriBuilder.Query` which will do necessary encoding and then get Uri using `UriBuilder.Uri`.

Prime example of hurting yourself by using code which is not supposed to be used like this

Comment: Could you add a complete utility function to this answer which works?

Comment: I second mafu on this: I read through the answer but don't have a conclusion. Is there a definitive answer to this?

Comment: I'd also like to see the definitive answer for this problem

Comment: The definitive answer to this problem is to use `var namedValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query)`, but then instead of using the returned NameValueCollection, immediately convert it to a Dictionary like so: `var dic = values.ToDictionary(x => x, x => values[x]);`  Add new values to the dictionary, then pass it to the constructor of `FormUrlEncodedContent` and call `ReadAsStringAsync().Result` on it.  That gives you a properly encoded query string, which you can assign back to the UriBuilder.

Comment: You actually *can* just use NamedValueCollection.ToString instead of all that, but only if you change an app.config/web.config setting that prevents ASP.NET from using the '%uXXXX' encoding: `<add key="aspnet:DontUsePercentUUrlEncoding" value="true" />`.  I wouldn't depend on this behavior, so it's better to use the FormUrlEncodedContent class, as demonstrated by an earlier answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26744471/88409

Comment: For people, who asked about alternative without double encoding issue - just use uriBuilder.Uri.ParseQueryString() instead of HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()

Answer (score 38):

You might want to check out [Flurl](https://flurl.dev) [disclosure: I'm the author], a fluent URL builder with optional companion lib that extends it into a full-blown REST client.

```
var result = await "https://api.com"
    // basic URL building:
    .AppendPathSegment("endpoint")
    .SetQueryParams(new {
        api_key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeApiKey"],
        max_results = 20,
        q = "Don't worry, I'll get encoded!"
    })
    .SetQueryParams(myDictionary)
    .SetQueryParam("q", "overwrite q!")

    // extensions provided by Flurl.Http:
    .WithOAuthBearerToken("token")
    .GetJsonAsync<TResult>();
```

Check out [the docs](https://flurl.dev) for more details. The full package is available on NuGet:

`PM> Install-Package Flurl.Http`

or just the stand-alone URL builder:

`PM> Install-Package Flurl`

Comment: Why not extend `Uri` or start with your own class instead of `string`?

Comment: Technically I did start with my own `Url` class. The above is equivalent to `new Url("https://api.com").AppendPathSegment...` Personally I prefer the string extensions due to fewer keystrokes and standardized on them in the docs, but you can do it either way.

Comment: Off topic, but really nice lib, I'm using it after seeing this. Thanks for using IHttpClientFactory as well.

Answer (score 7):

Along the same lines as Rostov's post, if you do not want to include a reference to `System.Web` in your project, you can use `FormDataCollection` from `System.Net.Http.Formatting` and do something like the following:

### Using [`System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormDataCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944841(v=vs.118))

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "ham", "Glaced?" },
    { "x-men", "Wolverine + Logan" },
    { "Time", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() },
}; 
var query = new FormDataCollection(parameters).ReadAsNameValueCollection().ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Since I have to reuse this few time, I came up with this class that simply help to abstract how the query string is composed.

```
public class UriBuilderExt
{
    private NameValueCollection collection;
    private UriBuilder builder;

    public UriBuilderExt(string uri)
    {
        builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
        collection = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
    }

    public void AddParameter(string key, string value) {
        collection.Add(key, value);
    }

    public Uri Uri{
        get
        {
            builder.Query = collection.ToString();
            return builder.Uri;
        }
    }

}
```

The use will be simplify to something like this:

```
var builder = new UriBuilderExt("http://example.com/");
builder.AddParameter("foo", "bar<>&-baz");
builder.AddParameter("bar", "second");
var uri = builder.Uri;
```

that will return the uri:
http://example.com/?foo=bar%3c%3e%26-baz&bar=second

Answer (score 4):

Good part of accepted answer, modified to use UriBuilder.Uri.ParseQueryString() instead of HttpUtility.ParseQueryString():

```
var builder = new UriBuilder("http://example.com");
var query = builder.Uri.ParseQueryString();
query["foo"] = "bar<>&-baz";
query["bar"] = "bazinga";
builder.Query = query.ToString();
string url = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: FYI: This requires a reference to [System.Net.Http](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http) as the `ParseQueryString()` extension method is not within `System`.

Answer (score 3):

Darin offered an interesting and clever solution, and here is something that may be another option:

```
public class ParameterCollection
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _parms = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public void Add(string key, string val)
    {
        if (_parms.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("The key {0} already exists.", key));
        }
        _parms.Add(key, val);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var server = HttpContext.Current.Server;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var kvp in _parms)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0) { sb.Append("&"); }
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}",
                server.UrlEncode(kvp.Key),
                server.UrlEncode(kvp.Value));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

and so when using it, you might do this:

```
var parms = new ParameterCollection();
parms.Add("key", "value");

var url = ...
url += "?" + parms;
```

Comment: You would want to encode `kvp.Key` and `kvp.Value` separately inside the for loop, not in the full query-string (thus not encoding the `&`, and `=` characters).

Comment: Thanks Mike. The other proposed solutions (involving NameValueCollection) didn't work for me because I'm in a PCL project, so this was a perfect alternative. For others who are working on the client side, the `server.UrlEncode` can be replaced with `WebUtility.UrlEncode`

Answer (score 2):

The [RFC 6570 URI Template library](https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-uritemplate) I'm developing is capable of performing this operation. All encoding is handled for you in accordance with that RFC. At the time of this writing, a beta release is available and the only reason it's not considered a stable 1.0 release is the documentation doesn't fully meet my expectations (see issues [#17](https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-uritemplate/issues/17), [#18](https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-uritemplate/issues/18), [#32](https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-uritemplate/issues/32), [#43](https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-uritemplate/issues/43)).

You could either build a query string alone:

```
UriTemplate template = new UriTemplate("{?params*}");
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
    { "param1", "value1" },
    { "param2", "value2" },
  };
Uri relativeUri = template.BindByName(parameters);
```

Or you could build a complete URI:

```
UriTemplate template = new UriTemplate("path/to/item{?params*}");
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
    { "param1", "value1" },
    { "param2", "value2" },
  };
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://www.example.com");
Uri relativeUri = template.BindByName(baseAddress, parameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer doesn't globally differ from the accepted/other answers. I just tried to create an extension method for the Uri type, which takes variable number of parameters.

```
public static class UriExtensions
{
    public static Uri AddParameter(this Uri url, params (string Name, string Value)[] @params)
    {
        if (!@params.Any())
        {
            return url;
        }

        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new(url);

        NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);

        foreach (var param in @params)
        {
            query[param.Name] = param.Value.Trim();
        }

        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();

        return uriBuilder.Uri;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://someuri.com")
    .AddParameter(
       ("p1.name", "p1.value"),
       ("p2.name", "p2.value"),
       ("p3.name", "p3.value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid double encoding issue described in taras.roshko's answer and to keep possibility to easily work with query parameters, you can use `uriBuilder.Uri.ParseQueryString()` instead of `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply using my Uri extension

#### Code

```
public static Uri AttachParameters(this Uri uri, NameValueCollection parameters)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    string str = "?";
    for (int index = 0; index < parameters.Count; ++index)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(str + parameters.AllKeys[index] + "=" + parameters[index]);
        str = "&";
    }
    return new Uri(uri + stringBuilder.ToString());
}
```

#### Usage

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/index.php").AttachParameters(new NameValueCollection
                                                                           {
                                                                               {"Bill", "Gates"},
                                                                               {"Steve", "Jobs"}
                                                                           });
```

#### Result

> http://www.example.com/index.php?Bill=Gates&Steve=Jobs

Comment: Didn't you forget URL encoding?

Comment: this is a great example of using extensions to create clear, useful helpers. If you combine this with the accepted answer you're on your way to building a solid RestClient

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "Darin Dimitrov", This is the extension methods.

```
 public static partial class Ext
{
    public static Uri GetUriWithparameters(this Uri uri,Dictionary<string,string> queryParams = null,int port = -1)
    {
        var builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
        builder.Port = port;
        if(null != queryParams && 0 < queryParams.Count)
        {
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
            foreach(var item in queryParams)
            {
                query[item.Key] = item.Value;
            }
            builder.Query = query.ToString();
        }
        return builder.Uri;
    }

    public static string GetUriWithparameters(string uri,Dictionary<string,string> queryParams = null,int port = -1)
    {
        var builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
        builder.Port = port;
        if(null != queryParams && 0 < queryParams.Count)
        {
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
            foreach(var item in queryParams)
            {
                query[item.Key] = item.Value;
            }
            builder.Query = query.ToString();
        }
        return builder.Uri.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var uri = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("URL of Api");
                
var requesturi = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(uri, "parameter_name",parameter_value);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(requesturi);
```

And then you can add request headers also eg:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", secretValue);
```

response syntax eg:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requesturi).Result;
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

A better method is to use an extension method for `HttpClient` that takes a `URL` and an object containing the query string parameters, and automatically generates the complete URL with the parameters included

```
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsyncWithQueryString<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, string url, T queryObject)
    {
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
        NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);

        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            string name = property.Name;
            string value = Convert.ToString(property.GetValue(queryObject, null));
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                query[name] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
            }
        }

        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();

        // Remove unnecessary parts of the URL such as protocol and port
        string finalUrl = uriBuilder.ToString().Replace("http://", "").Replace(":80", "");

        return await httpClient.GetAsync(finalUrl);
    }
}
```

To use this extension method, simply call it on an instance of `HttpClient`, passing in the base URL and an object containing the query string parameters

```
MyQueryObject queryObject = new MyQueryObject { Param1 = "value1", Param2 = "value2" };

HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsyncWithQueryString("https://example.com/api/carts", queryObject);
```

Answer (score -3):

I couldn't find a better solution than creating a extension method to convert a Dictionary to QueryStringFormat. The solution proposed by Waleed A.K. is good as well.

Follow my solution:

Create the extension method:

```
public static class DictionaryExt
{
    public static string ToQueryString<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        return ToQueryString<TKey, TValue>(dictionary, "?");
    }

    public static string ToQueryString<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, string startupDelimiter)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                result += startupDelimiter; // "?";
            else
                result += "&";

            result += string.Format("{0}={1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And them:

```
var param = new Dictionary<string, string>
          {
            { "param1", "value1" },
            { "param2", "value2" },
          };
param.ToQueryString(); //By default will add (?) question mark at begining
//"?param1=value1&param2=value2"
param.ToQueryString("&"); //Will add (&)
//"&param1=value1&param2=value2"
param.ToQueryString(""); //Won't add anything
//"param1=value1&param2=value2"
```

Comment: This solution is missing proper URL encoding of parameters and won't work with values that contain 'invalid' characters

Comment: Feel free to update the answer and add the encoding line missing, it's just a line of code!