# How to build query string for Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Assume that I have Web API method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string SomeAction([FromUri] ObjectA a, [FromUri] ObjectB b)
    {
        return Ok("test");
    }
```

How to call it using `HttpClient`? What is the best way to prepare appropriate query string for objects A and B?

**UPDATE**

`ObjectA` and `ObjectB` are complex objects... e.g.

```
public class ObjectA 
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public double Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

I can prepare query string for every specific case, but I'm interested to get any universal method that would allow to work with any objects...

For now I see only one possible solution - using reflection go through the list of properties and build query string. I assume that there should be some already implemented mechanism... am I wrong?

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096201/build-query-string-for-system-net-httpclient-get)    This might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you're including complex objects on the query string, I will assume they are being encoded in some manner, from what you're trying to do, it would have to be a default encoding or you won't be able to put them on the query string.

Normal routing would be:

```
/{controller}/{action}/{a}/{b}
```

or

```
/{controller}/{action}?a={content}&b={content}
```

Dependent upon how you have your routes configured and your preference on using query string parameters as opposed to "friendly" urls.

Alternately, the `MVC` framework will attempt to populate your object from values present in any available data location (i.e. `query string, cookies`, et. al.) where `variable names = property names`.  In this case, you *could* use something like this:

```
/SomeController/SomeAction?objectaProp1=abc&objectaProp2=def...
```

Hope this helps.