# .NET HttpClient add query string and JSON body to POST

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

How do I set up a .NET HttpClient.SendAsync() request to contain query string parameters and a JSON body (in the case of a POST)?

```
// Query string parameters
var queryString = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "foo", "bar" }
};

// Create json for body
var content = new JObject(json);

// Create HttpClient
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.baseaddress.com/");

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "something");
// Setup header(s)
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
// Add body content
request.Content = new StringContent(
    content.ToString(),
    Encoding.UTF8,
    "application/json"
);

// How do I add the queryString?

// Send the request
client.SendAsync(request);
```

Every example I've seen says to set the

```
request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queryString)
```

but then I lose my JSON body initialization in the `request.Content`

Comment: [`HttpRequestMessage` has a `RequestUri` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.requesturi(v=vs.118).aspx); use that to add the query string (you'll likely need to create a new `Uri` object and set `RequestUri` to that).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I did look into this and discovered that re-setting the `RequestUri` property with my endpoint + queryString info was overwriting the `HttpClient.BaseAddress` that I was setting globally on the `HttpClient` object. But this though path led me to the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I ended up finding `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.AddQueryString()` that was what I needed. This allowed me to add the query string parameters without having to build the string manually (and worry about escaping characters and such).

Note: I'm using ASP.NET Core, but the same method is also available through  `Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.WebUtilities.AddQueryString()`

New code:

```
// Query string parameters
var queryString = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "foo", "bar" }
};

// Create json for body
var content = new JObject(json);

// Create HttpClient
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.baseaddress.com/");

// This is the missing piece
var requestUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("something", queryString);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri);
// Setup header(s)
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
// Add body content
request.Content = new StringContent(
    content.ToString(),
    Encoding.UTF8,
    "application/json"
);

// Send the request
client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: I don't get it. So foo=bar is already a query string.. (key/val pair); Then you are adding another querystring something="foo=bar" , where key=something, value="foo=bar" ?

Comment: @joedotnot "something" in this context is going to be added onto the "BaseAddress" as part of the URI. So it would make the final URI `https://api.baseaddress.com/something?foo=bar`

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest that you use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for this purpose. It's basically a wrapper of the HttpWebRequest that does exactly what you want: makes it easy to compose url and body parameters and deserialize the result back.

Example from the site:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");

var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource

// easily add HTTP Headers
request.AddHeader("header", "value");

// add files to upload (works with compatible verbs)
request.AddFile(path);

// execute the request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: This is misleading. RestSharp is not a wrapper of HttpClient. HttpClient allows one to pass in a DelegatingHandler for authentication and retry logic. RestSharp is structured entirely differently, and would require installing Polly for handling the retry logic separately.

Comment: Yes, it's actually HttpWebRequest  that it is based on. I only meant it's a wrapper on top of .Net classes. I'll change text

Comment: Is there a way to pass the entire query string from a string, and not as a dictionary?

Answer (score -5):

This is simple and works for me:

```
responseMsg = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(locationSearchUri, new { NameLike = "Johnson" });
```

The body of the requests look like `{ NameLike:"Johnson" }`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question on how to add both a query string _and_ a json body to the same POST request.