# Question about putting a byte array into an API POST call in C#. How do you set the values that are required to be sent in a query string?

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net

The full url will be: https://dev.service.com/api/attachment/file?item=sc_req_item&id=1000&file_name=Some_file.pdf

The first requirement I have is to convert a PDF file into a byte array.
Easy enough:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Some_file.pdf");
```

Then I take that, and create a ByteArrayConent object.

```
var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson")
```

Then create an httpClientHandler, and an HttpClient:

```
 var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("FakeUser", "FakePassword")
        };

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://dev.service.com");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/pdf"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));
```

Then finally, I make the actual POST call, with the ByteArrayContent, but how do account the query string parameters?

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("api/now/attachment/file", byteArrayContent);
```

Comment: Why can't you just do `PostAsync("api/now/attachment/file?param1=abc&param2=xyz"`

Comment: @KJ Unfortunately our vendor is not being particularly helpful on this. This is their exact wording "The body of the POST should be the binary data of the attachment" so I'm not really getting a lot of support from them. I've never had to do this before so that's why I'm asking about here

Comment: So how do you know there are any parameters at all? Just send the body

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.AddQueryString()
Or
Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.WebUtilities.AddQueryString()
In order to add query parameters to your path.
I.E.

```
var requestUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("api/now/attachment/file", queryString);
```

And then pass that requestUri to PostAsync method.

Also answered here: [.NET HttpClient add query string and JSON body to POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290963/net-httpclient-add-query-string-and-json-body-to-post)