# HTTPClient POST in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I want to post data to a REST API, but it does not create the correct request:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/csv");
HttpResponseMessage response = null;

string baseUrl = ServiceUrl + "/api/v25/upload/test";

Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

parameters.Add("field1", "value1");
parameters.Add("field2", "value2");

MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
HttpContent content = new StringContent("long text...");
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
HttpContent fields = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
form.Add(content, "message");
form.Add(fields);

response = client.PostAsync(baseUrl, form).Result;
var message = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

It makes this URL:

> POST /api/v25/upload/test HTTP/1.1

and this would be the correct address:

> POST /api/v25/upload/test?field1=value1&field2=value2 HTTP/1.1

Where is the error in code, please?

Comment: WHy do you assume a POST that adds the fileds to the FORM would result in the parameters being added to the URL?

Comment: only get uses fields in the URL..

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpClient doesn't have an API that lets you build a query string. See [Build query string for System.Net.HttpClient get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096201/build-query-string-for-system-net-httpclient-get) for code that does that using `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`.

Or use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) instead:

```
var request = new RestRequest("/api/v25/upload/test", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("field1", "value1", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
```