# How to make URI with parameters in C# correctly?

Tags: c#, http, uri

Assume We have WebService like which accept a lot of parameters, different kinds of parameters with different type of values of parameters.

"https://contoso.com/sab/service.jssp?Param=Normal & JSONOBJECT=JSPJsonObj

How can I build URI with parameters in easy way? For example join parameters or create parameters with %20% format, or even may be create parameters like

oq=Microsoft+Access+Locks+Tables

Here I tried to build URI

```
    UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("https", "contoso.com", 8080, "service.jssp", "Param=Normal && JSONOBJECT=ITBS_UCN");
uriBuilder.Query += "Param3 = 3"

    Uri uri = uriBuilder.Uri;
```

As far as I understand Query parameters in browsers have different formatting rules, but I can NOT find class in .NET which ***encapsulate*** all these rules.

For example some of parameters are Json objects, some of them even binary encoded.

Comment: bellow link will help you, please have a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096201/build-query-string-for-system-net-httpclient-get/17096289

Comment: That should probably be the duplicate

Comment: It is almost duplicate, sry, I tried to search similar question, but was not able to find link about 17096201. Thx

Comment: HttpUtility have something to work with Query, but .NET defently need some cleanup in related to Query URL parameters parsing.