# How can I add a query string into HttpClient.BaseAdress in c#?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm trying to pass a query string into a BaseAddress but it doesn't recognize the quotation mark "?".

The quotation breaks the URI

First I create my BaseAddress

```
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid={Key}/");
```

Then I call the GetAsync method, trying to add another parameter

```
using (var response = await ApiHelper.httpClient.GetAsync("&q=mexico"))....
```

This is the URI the code is calling

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/&q=mexico
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build query string for System.Net.HttpClient get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096201/build-query-string-for-system-net-httpclient-get)

Comment: I think if you want to use that `BaseAddress` property effectively you need to use the `GetAsync` methods that take `System.Uri` as a parameter.  It will parse your partial url and append it to the base.  your querystring should start with a question mark `?q=mexico&other=2'

Comment: I'd be tempted to create a [`DelegatingHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh193679(v%3Dvs.118)) since I don't think this is possible without a handler or manually appending it to the URL in every request.

Comment: Hi, is there anything you're still unsure about with this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd be tempted to use a [`DelegatingHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh193679(v%3Dvs.118)) if you need to apply an API key to every single request:

```
private class KeyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly string _escapedKey;

    public KeyHandler(string key)  : this(new HttpClientHandler(), key)
    {
    }

    public KeyHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, string key) : base(innerHandler)
    {
        // escape the key since it might contain invalid characters
        _escapedKey = Uri.EscapeDataString(key);
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // we'll use the UriBuilder to parse and modify the url
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);

        // when the query string is empty, we simply want to set the appid query parameter
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uriBuilder.Query))
        {
            uriBuilder.Query = $"appid={_escapedKey}";
        }
        // otherwise we want to append it
        else
        {
            uriBuilder.Query = $"{uriBuilder.Query}&appid={_escapedKey}";
        }
        // replace the uri in the request object
        request.RequestUri = uriBuilder.Uri;
        // make the request as normal
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
httpClient = new HttpClient(new KeyHandler(Key));
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"); 

// since the logic of adding/appending the appid is done based on what's in
// the query string, you can simply write `?q=mexico` here, instead of `&q=mexico`
using (var response = await ApiHelper.httpClient.GetAsync("?q=mexico"))
```

** Note: If you're using ASP.NET Core, you should call `services.AddHttpClient()` and then use `IHttpHandlerFactory` to generate the inner handler for `KeyHandler`.

Comment: can you recommend any examples of doing this in .net core. Are you simply referring to calling .AddHttpMessageHandler<KeyHandler>()

Comment: Also wondering the same thing, could you expand the last part of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I work around it:

Http client impl:

```
namespace StocksApi2.httpClients
{
    public interface IAlphavantageClient
    {
        Task<string> GetSymboleDetailes(string queryToAppend);
    }

    public class AlphavantageClient : IAlphavantageClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public AlphavantageClient(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?apikey=<REPLACE WITH YOUR TOKEN>&");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");

            _client = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetSymboleDetailes(string queryToAppend)
        {
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_client.BaseAddress + queryToAppend);
            return await _client.GetStringAsync("");
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace StocksApi2.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SymbolDetailsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAlphavantageClient _client;

        public SymbolDetailsController(IAlphavantageClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Get([FromQuery]string function = "TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY",
            [FromQuery]string symbol = "MSFT", [FromQuery]string interval = "5min")
        {

            try {
                string query = $"function={function}&symbol={symbol}&interval={interval}";
                string result = await _client.GetSymboleDetailes(query);
                return Ok(result);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                return NotFound("Error: " + e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And in Startup.cs inside ConfigureServices:

```
  services.AddHttpClient();
  services.AddHttpClient<IAlphavantageClient, AlphavantageClient>();
```