# Building Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have been following this link: [Build query string for System.Net.HttpClient get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096201/build-query-string-for-system-net-httpclient-get)

but my situation was a little different and was not sure what the best approach would be. As of now I am thinking about going with a for loop but figured there might be a better approach.I have a list of parameters. I thought about just for looping over the list but that would make it where the querystring would be "?foo=1?foo=2"
See below example as to what I am looking for and what I have so far

```
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
List<String> foos = ...
query["foo"] = "1";
string queryString = query.ToString()
//Expected query string to be ?foo=1&foo=2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Specialized_NameValueCollection_Add_System_String_System_String_) method on `NameViewCollection`

With `Add` method you can add multiple values for a single key.

```
        var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        qs.Add("foo", "1");
        qs.Add("foo", "2");
```

`qs.ToString();` would give you `foo=1&foo=2`