# Adding GET parameters in a C# HTTP request

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I'm using xamarin forms to develop my android app. I'm done with sending data as `POST` requests now.

I'm currently using [GSM Modem (SMS)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsmmodem&hl=en) as a placeholder for other `SMS APIs` for `OTPs` in the future. This is the `URL` that the app gives me:
[Received URL](http://192.168.1.102:8090/SendSMS?username=sadiq&password=12345&phone=0300xxxxxxx&message=Text-Message)

As you can see, there are parameters available. Using my browser/PHP, I can easily refresh the page with new values in the parameters. However, in `C#` I'm quite unfamiliar with filling up these parameters.

I just want my app to send a signal or something to the `URL` with a dynamic phone and message parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build query string for System.Net.HttpClient get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096201/build-query-string-for-system-net-httpclient-get)

Answer (score 4):

What about string interpolation

```
var url = $"http://192.168.1.102:8090/SendSMS?username={yourusername}&password={yourpassword}&phone={yourphone}&message={yourtext}"
```

simplest way to send HTTP GET:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
await client.GetAsync(url)
```