# HttpClient: Add querystring parmas in HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I have a `Dictionary<string, object>` and I like to convert this dictionary into query string parameters and then use them with HttpRequestMessage and pass it to HttpClient.

I know we can pass `Dictionaly<string, string>`to FormUrlEncodedContent e.g `request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(params)` but here the value can be any type and that's why it's object.

Previously I was using RestClient where there was an option to use any kind of parameter value e.g `request.AddParameter("key", "value")`

Now is there any way to do that with httpClient? I want to use it in a get call so setting request.Content is not must. I can use something else e.g UriBuilder etc.

Comment: You can use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` along with a `UriBuilder`, [see here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK4wD4AEBMBGAWACgsAGAAizwDoB1AU2AG5jiA3CZcgR1XuQCe5ALzkAEggQAHAKoIoAGygIB1AAqcAzvQCKfQQGUEyWAHMAFACJLAShZFe/VQEEAJq6sAzAPbfLccktgTlt7KgBOc0dBagAVbyMTGAsbO1YiDi5gVEVXfhFyGHoAd3IZEwAhHIU85HMbYgBvYnJW8W9NBALLegAPCDApBXpqAGNvMH8Wtr0nAujVeMSzerhiAF8wvEjs3P44hOMV1PtiIA===)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096289/2501279) answer