# How to send GET request with parameters?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I send the parameters with GET request?

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{

    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryParameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response_type", "code"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", redirectUri),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("state", "qwe123"),
    };

    HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queryParameters);

    client.

    HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.GetAsync("https://uri", content); //here is mistake

    string responseBody = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
}
```

I tried to use KeyValuePair for configuring parameters.
Thanks!

Comment: Check out this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096201/build-query-string-for-system-net-httpclient-get

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You will need to add those params to the query string (url)

Comment: That's [not how to use HttpClient](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Answer (score 0):

`GetAsync` doesn't take `HttpContent` as a second param in any of its overloaded methods, please check supported overloaded methods [ms doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-6.0)

Have a look at similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45006503/6271132)

But, if you can change the `api` portion then better to change this to `POST` instead of `GET`

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://uri", new FormUrlEncodedContent(queryParameters));
var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```