HTTP client POST parameters
I need to POST to an endpoint in the following format
url?param1=val1&param2=val2
I tried using
Dictionary<string, string> jsonValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
jsonValues.Add("param1", "val1");
jsonValues.Add("param2", "val2");
var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(jsonValues);
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(endpointUrl, encodedContent).ConfigureAwait(false);

However the parameters do not seem to be being passed on to the endpoint.
What am I doing wrong or missing out?

Query params are not part of the HTTP request content.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096201/build-query-string-for-system-net-httpclient-get (I'm highly inclined to dupe) And following this post doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

use GetAsync rather than PostAsync

@Romylussone no. If you need to use the POST verb, it has to be PostAsync. And crafting the URL to have the right query params has nothing to do with the HTTP verb used.
