# ToString() of copied NameValueCollection doesn't output desired results

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `NameValueCollection` in a usercontrol that is initialized like so:

```
private NameValueCollection _nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
```

When I call the `ToString()` on this it generates a proper querystring which I can use for an updated url.

However, when I copy the `NameValueCollection` via its constructor like so:

```
var nameValues = new NameValueCollection(_nameValues);
```

And then try to form an url:

```
var newUrl = String.Concat(_rootPath + "?" + nameValues.ToString());
```

It outputs an url like this:

"http://www.domain.com?System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection"

How can I copy a `NameValueCollection` so that the `ToString()` method outputs desired results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameValueCollection to URL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865975/namevaluecollection-to-url-query)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is there are two actual types in your code. The fist one is `System.Web.HttpValueCollection` which has it's ToString method overriden to get the result you expect and the second one is `System.Collection.Specialized.NameValueCollection` which does not override ToString. What you can do, if you really need to use `System.Collection.Specialized.NameValueCollection` is to create an extension method.

```
 public static string ToQueryString(this NameValueCollection collection)
 {
        var array = (from key in collection.AllKeys
                     from value in collection.GetValues(key)
                     select string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value))).ToArray();
        return "?" + string.Join("&", array);
    }
```

and use it:

```
var newUrl = String.Concat(_rootPath,nameValues.ToQueryString());
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not `NameValueCollection` that provides the string formatting. That functionality is in an internal class `System.Web.HttpValueCollection` that is returned by `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`.

So you will not be able to achieve this behavior by using built in functionality. Your best bet would be to create an extension method that formats the values in a URL format.

Here is the method from `HttpValueCollection` class - you might be able to use it with some modifications.

```
// System.Web.HttpValueCollection
internal virtual string ToString(bool urlencoded, IDictionary excludeKeys)
{
    int count = this.Count;
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    bool flag = excludeKeys != null && excludeKeys["__VIEWSTATE"] != null;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        string text = this.GetKey(i);
        if ((!flag || text == null || !text.StartsWith("__VIEWSTATE", StringComparison.Ordinal)) && (excludeKeys == null || text == null || excludeKeys[text] == null))
        {
            if (urlencoded)
            {
                text = HttpValueCollection.UrlEncodeForToString(text);
            }
            string value = (text != null) ? (text + "=") : string.Empty;
            string[] values = this.GetValues(i);
            if (stringBuilder.Length > 0)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append('&');
            }
            if (values == null || values.Length == 0)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(value);
            }
            else
            {
                if (values.Length == 1)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(value);
                    string text2 = values[0];
                    if (urlencoded)
                    {
                        text2 = HttpValueCollection.UrlEncodeForToString(text2);
                    }
                    stringBuilder.Append(text2);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (j > 0)
                        {
                            stringBuilder.Append('&');
                        }
                        stringBuilder.Append(value);
                        string text2 = values[j];
                        if (urlencoded)
                        {
                            text2 = HttpValueCollection.UrlEncodeForToString(text2);
                        }
                        stringBuilder.Append(text2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

internal static string UrlEncodeForToString(string input)
{
    return HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.ToString()` on a name value collection will just give you the namespace it belongs to.

I suspect you want the key and value out of it, Assuming that it's the first in the collection why not just do:

```
var newUrl = String.Concat(_rootPath + "?" + nameValues.GetKey(0) + nameValues.Get(0));
```

You can have this as an extension method:

```
public static string ToString(this NameValueCollection nvc, int idx)
{
     if(nvc == null)
         throw new NullReferenceException();

     string key = nvc[idx];
     if(nvc.HasKeys() && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
     {
         return string.Concat(key, nvc.Get(key)); //maybe want some formatting here
     }

     return string.Empty;
}
```

Usage:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
string foo = nvc.ToString(0); //gets key + value at index 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way of working around this.

Instead of:

```
var nameValues = new NameValueCollection(_nameValues);
```

Do:

```
var nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(_nameValues.ToString()));
```

And this should create a new copy of correct type.