# How to add or update query string parameters to given URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

With C#.Net how can I add query string parameters to the URL if not present or if it present then updates the current values?

**For Example –** 
I have URL - http://example.com/Test.aspx?foo=bar&id=100 and I wanted to update foo value to chart and also wanted to add/append new parameters as hello = world and testStatus = true to query string.

So final expected output would be –
http://example.com/Test.aspx?foo=chart&hello=world&testStatus=true&id=100

Comment: You mean issue a GET request ?

Comment: No, I wanted to form URL with querystring values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following function which used in order to accomplish the required functionality :

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Get URL With QueryString Dynamically
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">URI With/Without QueryString</param>
        /// <param name="newQueryStringArr">New QueryString To Append</param>
        /// <returns>Return Url + Existing QueryString + New/Modified QueryString</returns>
        public string BuildQueryStringUrl(string url, string[] newQueryStringArr)
        {
            string plainUrl;
            var queryString = string.Empty;

            var newQueryString = string.Join("&", newQueryStringArr);

            if (url.Contains("?"))
            {
                var index = url.IndexOf('?');
                plainUrl = url.Substring(0, index); //URL With No QueryString
                queryString = url.Substring(index + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                plainUrl = url;
            }

            var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
            var qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(newQueryString);

            var queryData = string.Join("&",
                nvc.AllKeys.Where(key => !qscoll.AllKeys.Any(newKey => newKey.Contains(key))).
                    Select(key => string.Format("{0}={1}",
                        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nvc[key]))).ToArray());
            //Fetch Existing QueryString Except New QueryString

            var delimiter = nvc.HasKeys() && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryData) ? "&" : string.Empty;
            var queryStringToAppend = "?" + newQueryString + delimiter + queryData;

            return plainUrl + queryStringToAppend;
        }
```

**Function Usage -**

Suppose given url is - [http://example.com/Test.aspx?foo=bar&id=100](http://example.com/Test.aspx?foo=bar)

And you want to change **foo** value to **chart** and also you want to add new query string say **hello = world** and **testStatus = true** then -

**Input to Method Call :**

```
BuildQueryStringUrl("http://example.com/Test.aspx?foo=bar&id=100",
                new[] {"foo=chart", "hello=world", "testStatus=true"});
```

**Output :** [http://example.com/Test.aspx?foo=chart&hello=world&testStatus=true&id=100](http://example.com/Test.aspx?foo=Chart&hello=world&testStatus=true)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Redirect("{newUrl}?param1=value&param2=value")
```

Edited:

Just go trough Request.QueryString.

```
Dictionary params = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach (string key in Request.QueryString)
{
    var value = Request.QueryString[key];
    //
    //Do everything you need with params
    //
    params.Add(key, value);
}
Response.Redirect("{newUrl}?" + string.Join("&", params.Select(x=>string.Format("{0}={1}", x.Key, x.Value))));
```

Comment: I wanted to check if query string key is already exists/not, if exists then I want to modify it. In the above solution if URL already contains query string Key then it re-appends.

Comment: You can get these params by looping Request.QueryString. In the loop you can do everything you need.
string urlParams = string.Empty;
foreach(var param in Request.QueryString){
urlParams += string.Format("{0}={1}&", param.Key, param.Value);
}
Response.Redirect("{newUrl}?"+urlParams);

Instead of string you can use StringBuilder.

Comment: But I want to reform URL with existing + new + modified querystring parameters.

Comment: please, check my updated comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Request.QueryString["ParamName"] == null)
  //redirect with param in then URL
else
```

use the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771718/how-to-update-querystring-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you update query strings: [Update Query Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9772003/1004522). You can simply check for value, update and then redirect.