# How to insert a parameter from my application into an external url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

We have a site that when inserting the code of a user it shows the location of that user

I have a example URL:

http://npaa1215.example.com/gisb_prod/integration/coordUser.aspx?codUser=30071665&zoom=15

My idea is to use this URL in my application and pass the user code that is in my application to this URL

How could I insert a parameter that comes from my application, in the part of the URL that it asks the ***"codUser***"

In the example it is pointing to the user with ***"codUser=30071665"***

Would anyone have an idea or example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771718/how-to-update-querystring-in-c

Comment: It depends what you url returns. Just simple http get request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how i resolved the problem:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public RedirectResult RedirectTo(int id)
{
string location = GetLocation(id);
  return RedirectPermanent(location);
}

string url = "http://npaa1215.example.com/gisb_prod/integration /coordUser.aspx?codUser={0}&zoom=15";
private string GetLocation(int id)
{
  return string.Format(url, id);
}
```

View

```
href="@Url.Action("RedirectTo","Barcos", new { id = item.SapId })" class="btn btn-danger">
<span title="Excluir" class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you this simple solution

```
string COD_USER="30071665";
Response.Redirect("http://npaa1215.example.com/gisb_prod/integration/coordUser.aspx?codUser="+COD_USER+"&zoom=15");
```

I wish that help you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easier method is using `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString

```
string myUrl = "http://npaa1215.example.com/gisb_prod/integration/coordUser.aspx?zoom=15";
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(myUrl);
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
query["COD_USER"] = "30071665";
query["ANOTHER_QUERY_PARAMETER"] = "ParameterValue";
uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
myUrl = uriBuilder.ToString();
```

You can try with that, basically, you might use the `ParseQueryString` method and you can add with `query["COD_USER"] = "30071665"` or any other key that you want.

Answer (score -1):

The code below just take the userCode parameter and return the url with the given parameter inserted at the right place :

```
string url = http://npaa1215.example.com/gisb_prod/integration/coordUser.aspx?codUser={0}&zoom=15;

private string GetLocation(int userCode) 
{
  return string.Format(url, userCode);
}
```

Comment: Add some explanations so everybody can understand the code.

Comment: @aloisdg the code just take the userCode parameter and return the url with the given parameter inserted at his location