# c# rewrite url parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a simple task without a simple solution.
I have a parameter in the browser that needs to be changed or rewritten

for instance  www.contoso.com/countries.aspx?country=UK

all I need is to rewrite the parameter without checking the url so it might appear as:

www.contoso.com/countries.aspx?country=France

I have tried something like that but with no joy

```
string parameter2 = Request.QueryString["country"];
Context.RewritePath(parameter2.Replace("?country=", "France"));
```

Comment: WHEN are you trying to do this?

Comment: after an event like a button or hyperlink, the code should just change that parameter without changing anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

`var url = "www.contoso.com/countries.aspx?country={0}";`

`var country = "UK";`

`url = String.Format(url, country);`

Alternatively you can do:

`var url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;`

`var country = Request.QueryString["country"];`

`url = url.Replace(country, "UK");`

Then:

`Response.Redirect(url);`

Comment: Thanks, the url already comes as www.contoso.com/countries.aspx?country=UK, I need to repost the parameter.

Comment: ahhh so this will only work if you know the URL in advance which I am guessing you do not know it in advance

Comment: It worked really well, I tweaked your example a bit, the response.redirect made me understand how to repostback the string thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you not read the whole URL into a string, split it on the '?' and then add your new bit to the first part of the string?

Something like this:

```
    var url = Request.QueryString;
    var newUrl = url.split('?');
    url = newUrl[0] + "?country=France";
```

I dont know if that will work, its just a thought

Comment: Unnecessary. Why to do it like this? He has problems with rewriting, getting a parameter shouldn't be an issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the complete querystring, use

```
newVal = string.LastIndexOf("?");
```

and then

```
URL.Replace(oldVal, newVal);
```

OR if you have just one parameter in querystring and want to replace only value of it, use

```
newVal = string.LastIndexOf("=");
URL.Replace(oldVal, newVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3814281/1004522) detailed response for solution to your problem.