# altering Session parameters / variables

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-4.0, session-variables

as I was trying to test/debug my applications
by using `QueryString` as data to evaluate .

I was trying to implement same methods via session variables

in my [other post regarding QueryStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544893/altering-querystring-parameters-values) I was searching for a way to manipulate 
the QueryString via helper method ..

now I was trying to move on and triyng same thing  to Session Variables using same method as with QueryStrings

code is

```
    public static class Sesion
    {
    public sealed class Act
    {
    public const string edit = "edit", add = "add", remove = "remove", replace = "replace";
    }

            public static void Modify(string action, string New_Value, string CurSes_ParamName, string NewSession_paramName = null, bool redirectWithNewQuerySettings = false)
            {

                #region <<=========== reflect to readonly & set QueriString ReadOnly - false ============>>



                //HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["qs_key"]; 

                // reflect to readonly property 
                PropertyInfo isReadOnly = typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection).GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

                // make collection editable 
                isReadOnly.SetValue(HttpContext.Current.Session, false, null);

                #endregion
                switch (action)
                {
                    case Act.remove:
                        if (itsNotAnEmptySession())
                            HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(CurSes_ParamName);
                        break;
                    case Act.replace:
                        HttHttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(CurSes_ParamName);
                        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(NewSession_paramName , New_Value);
                        break;
                    case Act.edit:
                        HttpContext.Current.Session.Set(CurSes_ParamName, New_Value);
                        break;

                    case Act.add:
                        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(NewSession_paramName , New_Value);
                        break;

                }



                isReadOnly.SetValue(HttpContext.Current.Session, true, null);

            }
        }
}
```

the error i get on line that tries to set value of read only to false :
as i am still not yet experienced  enough with .net i couldn't understand 
where did i go wrong or ...is it totally impossible to implement that on session variables.

`Object does not match target type.`

trying it on QueryString and working with this method is fine as in this line of code:

```
isReadOnly.SetValue(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString, false, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just do the same with sessions :

First, `Http.Current.Session` is not a `NameValueCollection` (like `QueryString`), but an [HttpSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (which  explains your `Object does not match target type` message)

Then, `HttpSessionState` has an `IsReadonly` property, but... it's readonly (you can't set it). When the `IsReadonly` property from `NameValueCollection` is settable.

So... No way (at least this way).

Comment: thanks for the explanation . i tried just `Session.Add(param, value)` which works fine no problem adding to collection , although wanted to find out on editing a value , remove item from collection , will it be possible only remove first , add new(same parName), with new value ?

Comment: i think i have found the perfect solution in Application (state  variables) any drawbacks ? it allows what ever you need in first glance