# Change a the value of a GET / POST variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, get

I'm sure I'm over looking something simple, but I can't remember to save my life how to change a "GET" variable's value.

For example, say I have the web address `www.food.com/food.aspx?foodType=Healthy`

I know `Request.QueryString["foodType"]` can be used to retrieve the value, but if I want to say, change "`Healthy`" to "`Unhealthy`", how would I change the value on post back?

I'm using a on-click event right now for my button, but I am stuck on changing the value of "`foodType`." I tried using `Request.QueryString.Add("foodType", "UnHealthy");` but that did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is what your looking for but might help. If not I'll delete this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813934/change-single-url-query-string-value

Comment: are they calling the same url? Take note that Post method cannot be called by Get method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but you cannot modify the collection. As @Grant mentioned already the collection is read only.

If you use look at the source for [`HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) it creates the `QueryString` collection like this:

```
new HttpValueCollection(_queryStringText, true, true, Encoding.Default);
```

That second parameter sets the collection as read only.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you can't; the collection is read-only and only exists on returning the response as a by-product of the original request. You could use `Response.Redirect(url)`, where `url` is the original URL with a value changed - this will then re-issue a request and the server will get a chance to 'use' the new variable and serve the user with the result (directed to the new URL, even if the page is the same).